Redirect Nuitka's executable libs path
I have built a standalone Nuitka executable (not onefile), and I got an entry point and bunch of other '.so' libraries. My question is I want to redirect the path where nuitka looks for those deps on it starts. So I can copy the exeutable wherever I want and still working fine.
I have tried patchelf, chrpath and some environment variables such as (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Note: There's that option (--onefile-tempdir-spec) if you set onefile to true but not really convenient

